# Page views are not tracking properly in GA4. What is the solution

Tags: google-analytics, seo, google-analytics-4

Recently on one of my client's websites, I'm not getting proper data in GA4 in Engagement> Page and screen>  Page path and screen class. The views are showing 0.
[image: image description]
Does anyone know what are the solutions to this problem? How can I get the proper data?

I'm expecting the solution of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Some debugging steps:

1. Go to the pages where you expect analytics to fire, open the network tab, filer by `collect` see if the data is sent to ga.
2. Make sure the value of `tid` in the network call is the same as the measurement id of one of the data streams of the GA4 property you're looking at.

Add your findings to the question and we'll continue with debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the Google Tag Assistant in Google Tag Manager with the Debug view in Analytics? That would be my first step.

Open up your GTM account/container for your site, select Preview and open the Tag Assistant, and open the Debug view in GA4. Navigate over to the pages that you're having an issue with in the Assistant and see if debug registers any of those events.

Comment: we have already used the GTM, but it is still not working. If you have video or tutorial for this please share that.